# "The term 'mongosh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" error in vscode MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, vscode-extensions, mongodb-shell

I tried to use mongodb shell from vscode via it's extension. Connection was stablished successfully but when I try to open mongobd shell I got this error. [error screenshot : vscode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAnPf.png).  I copied the path in env variable and was able to use mongodb shell via its application but unable to do so in vscode.

I copied the bin location of mongodb shell in env variable. I was able  to successfully run mongodb shell via its application. [env variable setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JFsf.png)

Comment: do not use screenshots and use plain text instead

Comment: Did you extract the shell from the archive? You should add the folder to your `PATH` variable.